# Not work DTMF in FreeSwitch

Tags: sip, freeswitch, dtmf, sip-server

When an incoming call through the trunk, do not work DTMF, even in the console is no printed. In Asterisk trunk worked. DTMF type put rf2833 as Asterisk stood. On the inner rooms all works. Also if you run the applications start_dtmf,  bridge, and wait answer will take, DTMF start working, even if the subscriber is immediately reset after answering a call.

What could be wrong?

Comment: I add playback empty sound file after answer and DTMF worked, but this is bad decision.

Comment: It works through time.